# Python OrderedSet with .index() method

Tags: python, set, html-lists

Does anyone know about a fast OrderedSet implementation for python that:

- remembers insertion order
- has an index() method (like the one lists offer)

All implementations I found are missing the .index() method.

Comment: What implementation did you try?

Comment: for example http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/ and also blist

Comment: yes thats what it is about... need constant time... I will only need .add() and .index()

Comment: @Titusz It doesn't look like constant time is possible for that OrderedSet implementation. You'd have to maintain a separate list of indexes, which would kill the performance of `discard` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always add it in a subclass. Here is a basic implementation for the `OrderedSet` you linked in a comment:

```
class IndexOrderedSet(OrderedSet):
    def index(self, elem):
        if key in self.map:
            return next(i for i, e in enumerate(self) if e == elem)
        else:
            raise KeyError("That element isn't in the set")
```

You mentioned you only need `add`, `index`, and in-order iteration. You can get this by using an `OrderedDict` as storage. As a bonus, you can subclass the `collections.Set` abstract class to get the other set operations `frozenset`s support:

```
from itertools import count, izip
from collections import OrderedDict, Set

class IndexOrderedSet(Set):
    """An OrderedFrozenSet-like object
       Allows constant time 'index'ing
       But doesn't allow you to remove elements"""
    def __init__(self, iterable = ()):
        self.num = count()
        self.dict = OrderedDict(izip(iterable, self.num))
    def add(self, elem):
        if elem not in self:
            self.dict[elem] = next(self.num)
    def index(self, elem):
        return self.dict[elem]
    def __contains__(self, elem):
        return elem in self.dict
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dict)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.dict)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'IndexOrderedSet({})'.format(self.dict.keys())
```

You can't subclass `collections.MutableSet` because you can't support removing elements from the set and keep the indexes correct.

Comment: @Titusz if you really only need `add` and `index`, then maybe you can try something like what I added.

Comment: @agf this is a great answer... I tried out your dict based implementation and it works great. Than I found out, that I will also need to iterate over keys in order ;.). I could fix that with using self.dict = OrderedDict(). I will have to check wich implementation is faster...

Comment: @Titusz I updated and expanded the `dict` based implemetation a bit. There is really no reason for it not to support all the set operations `frozenset`s support, so I changed it to subclass `collections.Set`. I also gave it an appropriate `__repr__` so you can `print` it easily, and simplified the `__init__`.