# Python: order in a set of numbers

Tags: python, set

With this code:

```
print set(a**b for a in range(2, 5) for b in range(2, 5))
```

I get this answer:

```
set([64, 256, 4, 8, 9, 16, 81, 27])
```

Why it isn't sorted?

Comment: See [Python OrderedSet with .index() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998692/python-orderedset-with-index-method/7998819#7998819) for another `OrderedSet` question or http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/ for a good implementation; also [Does Python Have an Ordered Set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

Comment: what order were you expecting? `4, 8, 16, 9, 27, 81, 64, 256` or `4, 8, 9, 16, 27, 64, 81, 256` or something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sets are not ordered collections in python or any other language for that matter.

Sets are usually implemented using hash keys (hash codes). So order is probably related to how hash functions are used instead of natural order of its elements.

If you need order, please do consider using a list.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Andrew: Really?  Sounds like *the* answer to me.

Comment: `sorted(set(a**b for a in range(2, 5) for b in range(2, 5)))` converts it to ordered list

Answer (score 3):

Sets are by their nature unordered containers.  From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

They are implemented using a hash table, facilitating O(1) membership tests.  If you need an ordered set, try `OrderedDict.fromkeys()`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict.fromkeys(a**b for a in range(2, 5) for b in range(2, 5))
```