# Is there a typed collection tool in Python?

Tags: python, collections

I have several classes, and want to work with their collections like with a DB (or Django ORM, but simpler). Working with a DB would be a huge overhead, so I'd prefer having similar functionality in memory:

```
>>> node = Nodes.create(lat=X,lon=Y)
>>> node.id
1

>>> Nodes.all()
[<Node 1>]

>>> Nodes[1]  # by id
[<Node 1>]

>>> way_nodes = map(Nodes.create, ((X, Y), (Z, W)))
>>> way = Ways.create(way_nodes)
>>> way.nodes
[<Node 2>, <Node 3>]

>>> way.id
1
```

This is basically all what I need. Is there anything similar in Python or in custom packages?

If none, and I have to write my own, what's the best choice to inherit from?

Comment: Do you need to store the data for later use?

Comment: @Thomas Orozco: may be. But for now I'd prefer to stick with a simple code, so such things are not needed.

Comment: Then you should be using agf's solution - should you need to save at some point, consider the `shelve` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those seem like pretty basic requirements, why not code them into your classes?

```
from itertools import count, starmap

class Node(object):
    nextid = count(1).next
    nodes = {}
    def __init__(self, lat, lon):
        self.lat, self.lon = lat, lon
        self.id = self.nextid()
        self.nodes[self.id] = self

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        return cls.nodes.values()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Node %s>' % self.id

    @classmethod
    def byid(cls, id):
        return cls.nodes[id]

class Way(object):
    nextid = count(1).next
    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self.nodes = nodes[:]
        self.id = self.nextid()

node = Node(lat='X',lon='Y')
print node.id
print Node.all()
print Node.byid(1)

way_nodes = list(starmap(Node, (('X', 'Y'), ('Z', 'W'))))
way = Way(way_nodes)
print way.nodes
print way.id
```

Comment: If I needed no manipulation, this would work fine. But what if I want to add a node to a way?

Comment: @culebrón So you add a method to the Way class --- `def add(self, node): self.nodes.append(node)`. You could even inherit from one of the ABCs in the collections module if you wanted more sequence / collection-like features: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes for an example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998692/python-orderedset-with-index-method/7998819#7998819

Comment: I agree with the sentiment of this answer. There's no need to invoke complex data structures or relational databases for what you want to do, which is keep lists of node objects. (A plain `list` would actually be sane choice!)

Answer (score 2):

Working with a proper relational database is not necessarily a huge overhead. Are you aware of SQLite? (python module `sqlite3`) It can work with an in-memory database.

```
import sqlite3
db_conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
db_conn.execute("CREATE TABLE nodes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, lat FLOAT, long FLOAT);")
```

But for what you want to do, I'm not sure you need any relational semantics at all. (All you seem to be doing is creating indexable lists of `Nodes` - would a dict of `node_id : Node objects` do for you?

---

In passing, `map()` does exist in Python, but it's considered more "Pythonic" to use a list comprehension. The reasons for using list comprehensions are:

- The syntax is more intuitive
- List comprehensions combine the features of both `map()` and `filter()`.

Instead of saying

```
way_nodes = map(Nodes.create, ((X,Y),(Z,W))
```

we would say

```
way_nodes = [Nodes.create(*coord_pair) for coord_pair in ((X,Y),(Z,W))]
```

Both are equally correct, but the second form is preferred.

Comment: I use node_id objects right now. Will check out memory in sqlite, thanks!

Comment: I know, map is unpythonic, but still prefer it for brevity. I will need an R-tree index for a special case (searching points close one to another), so spatialite might be a good solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the builtin list type, if `node` is a list:

```
node[0] # get by id (id == 0)
node # .all()
```

If you'd like to create special classes to implement desired interface then by writing about the same amount of code as you would for your custom classes you could get full-power of relational databases using [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
# get node id
node.id # -> 1
# get all nodes
Node.query.all() # -> [<Node 1>, <Node 2>, <Node 3>, <Node 4>]
# get all nodes associated with the `way`
way.nodes # -> [<Node 2>, <Node 3>, <Node 4>]
# get `way` with id == 1
Way.query.get(1) # -> <Way 1>
# get all `way`s the node belongs to
node.ways.all() # -> []
# get all nodes with longitude == Y
Node.query.filter_by(lon=Y).all() # -> [<Node 1>, <Node 2>]
```

Here's the code that implements it:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Float, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr

# declare models
class Base(declarative_base()):
    __abstract__ = True

    # provide id for each object
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        Session.add(obj) # add to db session
        return obj

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        """Use lowercased classname for table name."""
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{name} {id}>".format(name=self.__class__.__name__, id=self.id)

class Node(Base):
    lat = Column(Float)
    lon = Column(Float)

    def __init__(self, lat, lon):
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon

# define many-to-many relationship
nodes = Table(
    'nodes', Base.metadata,
    Column('node_id', Integer, ForeignKey('node.id')),
    Column('way_id', Integer, ForeignKey('way.id'))
    )

class Way(Base):
    nodes = relationship(Node, secondary=nodes,
                         backref=backref('ways', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self.nodes = nodes
```

#### Test

```
# create in memory db
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
# one db session per thread
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base.query = Session.query_property() # allow queries via Model.query
#
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


X, Y, Z, W = range(4)
node = Node.create(lat=X, lon=Y)
way_nodes = [Node.create(*args) for args in [(X, Y), (Z, W)]]
way = Way.create(way_nodes)
way.nodes.append(Node(10, 11))

Session.commit()
assert node.id == 1
assert node.ways.all() == []
assert Node.query.filter_by(lon=Y).count() == 2
assert way.id == 1
assert any(x.lat == 10 and x.lon == 11 for x in way.nodes)
assert Node.query.filter_by(lat=10, lon=11).one()
assert Way.query.get(1) == way

# remove context (thread) -local session
Session.remove()
```